# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool') Document Snapshot Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to check the groupId If the user has the document field or not If yes go to HalfScreen If no say Text('No data') But the problem is it always says _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool')

```
        snapshot.data!.get("groupId")
                        ? const Text('No data')
                        : const Expanded(
                            flex: 5,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                              child: HalfScreen(),
                            )),
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `snapshot.data!.get("groupId")` doesn't return a `bool`. It returns a `Future` (`Future<QuerySnapshot<T>>` to be precise). You should `await` it and evaluate the result.